# Cannot remove footer links of a website

Tags: html, css, web, footer

i have a blogger theme and it has footer links of the owner of the template which is this: http://www.oddthemes.com/2015/06/style-magazine-blogger-template.html

if i delete the link of the website then it gets redirected to oddthemes.com so how can i get rid of them.

Please tell me if you want more info.

```
<div class="lefts">
  Copyright © 2014 
  <a class="sitename" href="http://style-oddthemes.blogspot.in/" title="Style Magazine">Style Magazine.
  </a>
  Designed by <a href="http://www.oddthemes.com/" id="blogg" rel="dofollow">OddThemes</a>
```

Comment: The author requires you keep the credits for the *Free* version of that particular theme. It is sort of unethical to remove the credit. "*Free Version:  Irremovable Footer Links, one can't remove it because removing will redirect your website to our website.*"

Comment: i was about to give my client the template. so i wouldn't want him to find about the template is from oddthemes. So i was thinking of this step

Comment: Of course not. you wouldn't want your customer to know they paid for a free theme.

Comment: Thankyou for commenting.

Comment: What's your website link?

Comment: My website is http://www.waafrikaonline.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap the code you want removed with a div like this:

```
<div class="someDiv">
    Designed by <a href="http://www.oddthemes.com/" id="blogg" rel="dofollow">OddThemes</a>
</div>
```

Then add this to your css:

```
.someDiv {
    display:none;
}
```

---

I wouldn't recommend removing the attribute though as the design **does not belong to you**.

You should contact the designer and purchase it from him for a lower price than what you're selling it for. That way, both you as well as the designer will profit from the site.

Answer (score 1):

> Using jquery or JavaScript  to you can remove owner site(link and text) from footer.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>  
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$(".lefts").append("Design by <a href='http://www.waafrikaonline.com/'> OddThemes</a>. All Rights Reserved.");
$("#mycontent").find('a').attr("href", "http://www.waafrikaonline.com/");
$("#mycontent").find('a:first').text("WAAFRIKA ONLINE");
});  
</script>
```

> By using css (class or id) to you can append "href" links and "text".i
>   have modified as per your site if it wont work just replace exact css(class
>   and id).

Answer (score 0):

I would say it's probably something in your JS checking that you have not altered the code, try checking there. Also, Wouldn't this be copyright infringement, since you are not attributing the original author?

Comment: Thankyou for the answer, i don't know much about copyright. so you are suggesting i mustn't remove the links?

Comment: You could hide them, but I definitely would not take them out